# Search by category list - django

Tags: python, django

I have simple search application
How can I search by Categories
using `<select><option></select>`

the result :

```
results = Adv.objects.filter(title__icontains=query).filter(cate__name__icontains=query)
```

here is the code :

models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Adv(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    namecar = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cate = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

view

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
      query = request.GET['q']
      results = Adv.objects.filter(title__icontains=query).filter(cate__name__icontains=query)
   #   print results.query 
    else:
      query = ""
      results = None
    template = loader.get_template('search/search1.html')
    context = Context({ 'query': query, 'results': results, 'city_list': ChoiceCity.objects.all() })
    response = template.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

url

```
(r'^search1/$', 'car.search.views.search'),
```

template

```
<form method="get" action="/search1/">
<p><label for="id_q">Search:</label>
<input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to make Advanced search and be by category list

,Sorry My english Not good

Comment: I have added an answer please take a look let me know if you any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to be able to filter the result based on the category. I would suggest adding a category selection drop down in your template. This would require you to send the category objects into the template so, it could be rendered

```
<form method="get" action="/search1/">
<p><label for="id_q">Search:</label>
<input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}" />
<select name="category">
  {% for category in categories %}
    <option value="{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
  {% endfor %}  
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>



 def search(request):
        if 'q' in request.GET:
          #Get the selected category id 
          sel_category = request.GET.get('category', None)
          #If it exists, get the category object
          if sel_category: 
                category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk = sel_category)
          query = request.GET['q']
          results = Adv.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
          #If category objects exists filter the result set based on that
          if category:
                    results =results.filter(cate__name__icontains=category.name)
       #   print results.query 
        else:
          query = ""
          results = None
          categories = Category.objects.all()
        template = loader.get_template('search/search1.html')
        context = Context({ 'query': query, 'results': results, 'city_list': ChoiceCity.objects.all(), 'categories':categories })
        response = template.render(context)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: A last questions
How do I add an option in the <select>
Allows me to search in all categories

Comment: Updated the answer take a look